# SQL how to copy data from 1 table to specific row of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy the `CV` column with the `varbinary` info from the table `TBLPERSON` to the `TBLPERSONREPRESENTATION` table into the `CV` column, where the row has the same `PersonID` as the `TBLPERSON`. What’s the best way to do this?

**TBLPERSON**

```
PersonID | Name   |  CV

1_ _ _ _ | Jo _ _ | **varbinary**
2_ _ _ _ | Cash _ | **varbinary**
3_ _ _ _ | Blade _| **varbinary**
```

**TBLPERSONREPRESENTATION**

```
PersonRepresentationID    | PersonID   | Name  | CV
1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 1 _ _ _ _ _| Jo    | NULL
2 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 2 _ _ _ _ _| Cash  | NULL
3 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ | 3 _ _ _ _ _| Blade | NULL
```

So to be clear I want to copy the `varbinary` to the `CV` column in `TBLPERSONREPRESENTATION`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE TBLPERSONREPRESENTATION
SET CV = P.CV
FROM TBLPERSON P INNER JOIN
     TBLPERSONREPRESENTATION R ON P.PersonID = R.PersonID
;
```

Comment: `update from`? There's no mention of it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This question isn't specifically MySQL.

Comment: @Yuck: Anyway, never seen this construct before. Do you have a link where I can read about it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - it's common in SQL Server for `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`

Comment: This construct has always been around as far as I remember, even before MS bought Sybase.

Answer (score 2):

```
update TBLPERSONREPRESENTATION pr
set CV = (select CV from TBLPERSON p where pr.PersonID = p.PersonID)
```